# Прокрутка к якорю из URL страницы при загрузке

Tags: javascript

Добрый день, коллеги! Нужна помощь, хочу реализовать следующий эффект: **при загрузке страницы если в адресе сайта будет находиться якорь (например, `mysite.ru#anchor`), тогда прокрутить страницу до этого якоря!**

Использую скрипт прокрутки до якоря:

```
$(window).load(function () {
      $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#anchor').offset().top}, 2000);
      return false;});
```

Он нормально работает, если явно прописывать в него конкретный якорь `#anchor`, но если прописать этот якорь еще и в адресе `mysite.ru#anchor`, то после обновления - страница сразу опускается до якоря без анимации (как в обычном режиме), а скрипт начинает выполняться потом (когда страница уже прокручена), т.е. после инициализации элемента с `id = "anchor"` в DOM, браузер срабатывает раньше, чем скрипт.

Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы было наоборот, или вообще как добиться желаемого?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если запускать функцию после загрузки содержимого, то вполне логично, что у вас будет срабатывать дефолтный переход к якорю в html, а после прогрузки всего html будет срабатывать скрипт. Поэтому вам нужно как-то запретить переход к якорю по дефолту. [[@TheDoctor](/users/31688/thedoctor)](/users/31688/thedoctor) правильно написал, что нужно копать в сторону `window.location.hash`.

Например, если сильно не заморачиваться, можно использовать такой вариант:

```
<script>
  window.hashName = window.location.hash;
  window.location.hash = '';

  $(window).load(function () {
      $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(window.hashName).offset().top}, 2000);
      return false;});
   });

</script>
```

Первая часть скрипта соотвественно должна быть вызвана до загрузки html.

Comment: О Мастер, зачем очищать хэш?  
Вдруг он будет нужен?

Comment: @TheDoctor, если будет нужен, то можно вернуть обратно в любой момент после загрузки страницы: `window.location.hash = window.hashName;`

Comment: @MasterAlex, глобальные переменные - это вообще зло, ну да ладно, гораздо интереснее другое - вдруг хэш будет `#first`, а прокрутка привязана к `#second`?  
Тогда юзер увидит прокрутку к `#second`, хотя просил вообще другое.

Comment: @TheDoctor, в моём скрипте прокрутка привязана к хэшу, откуда возьмётся `second`? Автор поставил конкретный хэш тоже для примера.

Comment: @MasterAlex, поменял? Когда я читал там был хэш ТС'а. Или последняя рюмка была лишней?..

Comment: @TheDoctor, или стакан :) на этот случай всегда есть [история изменений поста][1]

[1]: http://hashcode.ru/revisions/411214/

Comment: @MasterAlex, странно это... Но тогда всё отлично, молодец!  
P. S. Я не пью, спортсмен, не комсомолец и просто красавец :)

Comment: Спасибо, работает! window.location.hash я тоже использовал, вставлял напрямую в '$(window.location.hash).offset().top', благодаря чему страница сначала опускалась сразу до якоря, а если я успевал прокрутить вверх она уже плавно опускалась:) я тоже думал что надо как-то умудриться ссылку поменять, но не знал как, как и не знал то, что window.location.hash можно обнулить, а в этом и была разгадка), спасибо всем и @MasterAlex, желаемого эффекта достиг!

Answer (score 0):

А какой глюк выходит?
Можно проверять `window.location.hash` на наличие там прокручиваемого тэга. Если есть - ничего не крутим и не анимируем, т.к. браузер сам установит прокрутку.
[Ман.](http://javascript.ru/window-location)

Answer (score 0):

Доработанный исправленный скрипт:

```
<script>
if (window.location.hash!='') {
    window.hashName = window.location.hash;
    window.location.hash = '';
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('html').animate({scrollTop: $(window.hashName).offset().top}, 2000, function() {
            window.location.hash = window.hashName;
        });
    });
}
</script>
```

Якорь должен быть с атрибутом id, который дублирует name:

```
<a id="content" name="content"></a>
```